# Why does Pagy return nil in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pagy

`@pagy` is returning `nil` in my view (`#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'pages' for nil:NilClass>`).

It works as expected in the console:

```sh
> @pagy.pages
=> 25
> pagy_nav(@pagy)
=> "<nav class=\"pagy-nav pagination\"...
```

I've added the Pagy includes in the Folders Controller:

```rb
class FoldersController < ApplicationController
  include Pagy::Backend

  get '/folder/:permalink' do
    @pagy, @pagination = pagy(Article.all)
  end

  helpers do
    include Pagy::Frontend
  end

end
```

I'm calling it in the Folder's Show View:

```rb
<%= pagy_nav(@pagy) if @pagy.pages > 1 %>
```

Any ideas why `@pagy` is returning `nil` inside the view?

Any advice on using Pagy in a Sinatra app?

Comment: Maybe the request does not get to the action where you define `@pagy`, while you have the view using it. Try to add `raise "this works!"` in the same action to be sure that you hit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@pagy` needs to be called *before* your `erb` call.

Like this:

```rb
@pagy, @articles = pagy(@articles.order(position: :desc), items: 50)
erb :'folders/show_folder'
```

Not like this:

```rb
erb :'folders/show_folder'
@pagy, @articles = pagy(@articles.order(position: :desc), items: 50)
```